# MediaPlayer.create() para de funcionar após alguns sons

Tags: java, android

Olá, eu coloquei um som diferente para tocara a cada botão pressionado, porem depois de 4 starts ele simplesmente para.

Codigo:

```
 numero = random.nextInt(numeros.length);
 MediaPlayer soundID = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("s" + numeros[numero], "raw", getPackageName()));
 soundID.start();
```

Erro:

```
08-06 02:04:50.604 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-06 02:04:52.089 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-06 02:04:54.259 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-06 02:04:55.368 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-06 02:04:58.179 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
08-06 02:04:58.202 15072-15083/lordlokon.contarapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
08-06 02:04:58.202 15072-15072/lordlokon.contarapp E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que usar o *MediaPlayer* deverá fazer o *release* dele após ele ter terminado de tocar o som.

Para ser notificado dessa ocorrência implemente a interface *OnCompletionListener* e passe-a ao método `setOnCompletionListener()` do *MediaPlayer*

```
//Atributo para guardar a referência ao *MediaPlayer*
private MediaPlayer soundID;
```

Altere o seu código para:

```
//Se algum som ainda estiver a tocar pára-o
releasePlayer();

numero = random.nextInt(numeros.length);
soundID = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier("s" + numeros[numero], "raw", getPackageName()));

soundID.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //No final de tocar liberta o media player para poder ser novamente utilizado
        releasePlayer()
    }
});

soundID.start();
```

Método para libertar o *MediaPlayer*

```
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (soundID != null) {
        soundID.stop();
        soundID.release();
        soundID = null;
    }
}
```